# Get illustration width and height

Tags: canvas, width, fabricjs

Im trying to get the illustrations width and height of an Fabric JS object. The built in function found is that I can retrive the W & H of the total object, but not the illustration. How do I solve this? Im looking to get the measure for the blue arrows, not the green as Im able to get now.

One way I was trying was to remove the padding around the illustration with "padding: 0", although some sort of padding always appears and is dynamically increasing when you make the object wider.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPQf9.png)

Comment: Found this thread which covers my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548747/fabricjs-how-to-scale-object-but-keep-the-border-stroke-width-fixed

Comment: so answer your question or delete it